# Dropdown menu (left, center and right)?

Tags: html, css

Did I make a dropdown menu where I run into problems when I align the menu on the right side in the browser? The last submenu item sits further out of the browser's box-model. How do I control the placement of the dropdown (left, center and right)? Follow the link below:

```css
.navbar-menu-one {
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 23px;
  display: block;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 200px;
  display: none;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

ul ul li {
  display: block;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

.item-nav-right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar-menu-one item-nav-right">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu</a>
      <ul style="">
        <li>
          <a href=""></a>Link</li>
        <li>
          <a href=""></a>Link</li>
        <li>
          <a href=""></a>Link</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href=""></a>Link</li>
        <li>
          <a href=""></a>Link</li>
        <li>
          <a href=""></a>Link</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Link : [Codepen](https://codepen.io/johnnycoffee/pen/QWvbdmx)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code and the existing resources, I managed to fix it by implementing the syntax below and the  element

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row-reverse;
direction: rtl;
```

improvement :

```
ul {
  position: relative;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  direction: rtl;
}
```